# Setting up subdomains in Rails 3 on AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My rails app has the following subdomains: my, admins, locations

I have set up my routes file as follows:

routes.rb

```
match '/' => 'admins#index', :constraints => { :subdomain => "admins" }
match '/' => ‘users#index', :constraints => { :subdomain => "my" }
match '/' => ‘locations#index', :constraints => { :subdomain => “locations” }
```

Locally, this works fine…If I point to admins.lvh.me, or my.lvh.me, it points to the right page.

My issue is when I deploy it to AWS ElasticBeanstalk. Elasticbeanstalk makes my app accessible at aws_assigned_name.elasticbeanstalk.com. So I added a CNAME to my DNS as follows:

```
my.mydomain.com CNAME aws_assigned_name.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

Can I do this multiple times, one for each subdomain? So my DNS would look like:

```
my.mydomain.com CNAME aws_eb_assigned_name.elasticbeanstalk.com
admins.mydomain.com CNAME aws_eb_assigned_name.elasticbeanstalk.com
locations.mydomain.com CNAME aws_eb_assigned_name.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

Or what is the generally accepted method to handle this?

Comment: and did your CNAME `my.mydomain.com CNAME aw.eb.com` work?

Comment: my.mydomain.com CNAME aw.eb.com works, in fact having all those as CNAMES look like they work (so far...I am still testing different scenarios). I just wasn't sure that was the recommended way of handling it or not

Comment: Cool, ye I guess it's the recommended way. Works good so far :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a wildcard CNAME. This will redirect all your subdomains.

```
*.mydomain.com CNAME aws_eb_assigned_name.elasticbeanstalk.com
```